# spring batch - FlatFileItemReader - token is of type object

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am using spring batch and spring data jpa in my application first time.
 Spring batch reads a text file says aCode,aName,sCode.
 I have a POJO which maps these keys like below, one the the keys is of another type of object

```
 public class Pojo{
  private AnotherObject sCode;  
  private String aName;
  private String aCode;
 }
```

Below is my reader in BatchConfiguration class.
 How do I handle this AnotherObject.
 I get an error saying:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'sCode' of bean class [Pojo]: Duplicate match with distance <= 5 found for this property in input keys: ["sCode","aCode","aName"]. (Consider reducing the distance limit or changing the input key names to get a closer match.)

```
 @Bean
  @StepScope
  public FlatFileItemReader<Area> reader(
      @Value("#{stepExecutionContext[fromId]}") final String fromId,
      @Value("#{stepExecutionContext[toId]}") final String toId,
      @Value("#{stepExecutionContext[name]}") final String name) {
    FlatFileItemReader<Area> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    try{

      reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("area_temp.txt"));   
      LineMapper<Area> areaMapper = createAreaLineMapper();
      reader.setLineMapper(areaMapper);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return reader;
  }

  private LineMapper<Area> createAreaLineMapper() {
    DefaultLineMapper<Area> areaLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();

    LineTokenizer areaTokenizer = createAreaTokenizer();
    areaLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(areaTokenizer);

    FieldSetMapper<Area> areaInformationMapper = createAreaInformationMapper();
    areaLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(areaInformationMapper);

    return areaLineMapper;
}

 private LineTokenizer createAreaTokenizer() {
    DelimitedLineTokenizer areaLineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
    areaLineTokenizer.setDelimiter("|");
    areaLineTokenizer.setNames(new String[]{"sCode","aCode","aName"});
    return areaLineTokenizer;
}
 private FieldSetMapper<Area> createAreaInformationMapper() {
    BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Area> areaMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
    areaMapper.setTargetType(Area.class);
    return areaMapper;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception is pretty self explanatory.  `BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper` allows for fuzzy matching on the names.  You can configure how fuzzy it is via the distance.  You can read more about setting that distance in the javadoc here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/mapping/BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper.html#setDistanceLimit-int-

Comment: Thanks for your input. Why should we override the distancelimit, when the names in pojo and {"sCode","aCode","aName"} match. Should the distancelimit be > 5 or less than 5

Comment: after I set it to areaMapper.setDistanceLimit(0); That issue is gone but I got another error saying "Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: 
Invalid property 'ePCode' of bean class [Pojo]: Bean property 'ePCode' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. 
Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?"  I am sure, the AnotherObject has public getter and public setter for ePCode

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this issue. I think this line of code

```
areaLineTokenizer.setNames(new String[]{"sCode","aCode","aName"});
```

should be changed to:

```
areaLineTokenizer.setNames(new String[]{"sCode","aName","aCode"});
```